# Magento 2.3.3 Luma theme Checkout not showing payment options

Tags: magento2.3.3

Well, Ive seen more questions on this topic but there doesn't seem to be an answer, so let me try with my specific problem

Magento: 2.3.3 stock, nothing added
Theme: Luma (nl_NL mode)
Payment methods: Bank tranfer (enabled)
Added one test product, set taxes, customer class, pricing, all ...

Cannot get anything, not even page title h1 to render on the page. It just shows the header and footer, nothing else.

Tried:

- setup:upgrade
- setup:di:compile
- setup:static-content:deploy -f
- setup:static-content:deploy nl_NL -f
- cache:clean
- cache:flush

Nothing works ... you can see it here: https://blokjeswebshop.nl/checkout/

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found it ... in system.log I saw this:

[2019-12-05 12:23:20] main.CRITICAL: Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /vendor/magento/module-shipping/Model/Config.php on line 68 [] []

Which indicates the shipping options, there weren't any as I hadn't installed Magento_OfflineShipping or any of the default US shippers.

After installing Magento_OfflineShipping via commandline:
php bin/magento module:enable Magento_OfflineShipping
... setup:di:compile
... setup:static-content:deploy nl_NL -f
... cache:flush

The page now works ! Woohoo ...